# How can I uniquely Identify the computer where my website is opening?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a personal portal of my client. 
They want to restrict the user machines. Just those machine whose info is saved in DB can access the site. 
How can I restrict the users (Mac address, serial number or any other unique number) ?

Comment: I beleive, you will need certificates

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5048066/how-to-uniquely-identify-a-computer

Comment: Simple way is to generate some key and provide it to user that uses machine. When user access your DB he must provide this key and your server validate it. It's very primitive explanation of concept.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123639/how-to-resolve-hostname-from-local-ip-in-c-net

Comment: When I read your question I thought of the dongle method. Seems more secure than an approved IP list but at a cost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481148/how-can-one-make-a-web-site-accessible-only-when-someone-has-a-dongle

Comment: Secure Tunnel (Cert) + Whitelist?

Comment: I want to say, for example if I save my PC's mac address/identying number or any other unique id that can be used for this purpose. On login time I can check if I am Login with the same machine then its ok and if I am Login from any different machine then it should blocked.